# My containerized Node/React application works on Kubernetes locally, need help getting it to run on GCP GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I'm taking a course on Udemy to learn Microservices with Node for work. I have completed the first project which consists of 6 microservices, 1 being the react app and 5 services handling the logic. It works on my pc running Kubernetes through Docker Desktop but I am struggling getting it to run on Google Cloud GKE.

The original(local) project uses nginx to handle the ingress and Skaffold to manage the building of containers. I tried to launch it as is in GKE and everything seemed to work, pods and services started, but the external IP from the load balancer gave an nginx 404 error.

Then I decided I would try to deploy the containers on GKE without using nginx and use GCP's built in Load Balancers and services. I have the pods running but I think I'm getting lost with mapping the services/ports/Load Balancer to get it to work properly.

I have spent all day reading Google's documentation and they only provide examples for single service applications so I can't figure out how to make the 6 services all come together and work. I'm pretty new to GKE and would love some pointers from someone who is familiar with it.

Here is a link to my GitHub for the [project](https://github.com/CBoton/blog), and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Took a quick look at https://github.com/CBoton/blog/blob/master/infra/k8s/ingress-srv.yaml.  GCE Ingress does not support regex in paths and you can only use the `*` as the last character in the path and it must follow a `/`.  Also, you still have `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` in your Ingress as well.

Comment: When you were trying to use nginx Ingress, I assume you have deployed the nginx Ingress controller on GKE?

Comment: Refer this [documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/exposing-multiple-portsservices-same-load-balancer-sunil-agarwal) for more information on exposing multiple services in GKE.

Comment: @ Gari Singh, yes I had the nginx ingress conttroller installed on GKE. If the regex is not supported how would I call the path /posts/:id/comments when :id isn't static? I've been reading documentation all morning and my brain is melting, thanks for the help

Comment: You won't be able to use GCE Ingress with the paths like you currently have.  I see two options:  1) go back to Nginx Ingress (we can help) 2) we can change the path mappings (but to do that would need to possibly modify the microservices endpoints)

Comment: Did you refer this [documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/exposing-multiple-portsservices-same-load-balancer-sunil-agarwal) which clearly explains Exposing multiple ports/services on same Load Balancer in Kubernetes

Comment: @Curtis Botonis, provide more information regarding **"I can't figure out how to make the 6 services all come together and work."** Do you mean a) Exposing multiple services on same Load Balancer in Kubernetes or b) Hosting multiple services on a single cluster. Let me know if you are looking at other scenario?

Comment: @ Gari Singh, I think I want to leave nginx and go to gke native methods, I believe this will be better for me moving forward in my job role.

@Goli Nikitha, Here is what I believe needs to happen. The React App Client should be exposed on the LB. The React App only calls 3 API's, which should be handeled by ingress controller
post(http://posts.com/posts/${postId}/comments)
post(http://posts.com/posts/create)
get('http://posts.com/posts')

Whenever these endpoints are called they post to the event-bus service. All the services should be communicating internally via clusterIp/ports

Comment: --contnued from last comment: Each container is running in its own pod in the same cluster. I just need to figure out how to connect the dots with the services.
I did read the doumentation you provided, I don't think that is the solution I am looking for though, but I could be wrong. I just started learning Docker/Kubernetes last week and don't really have anyone at work to turn too so I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

ClusterIP can resolve the issue.

Kubernetes creates a stable IP address that is accessible from nodes in the cluster.

If we have 3 different workloads(containers) running in pods of 3 different nodes and if we need to establish a connection between them, first we need to setup clusterIP service for 3 different nodes separately and then try interacting with them with their clusterIP and the TCP port specified in the port field.These requests are forwarded to one of the member Pods on the TCP port specified in the targetPort field.

Go through this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4Z7visMM4E) for a detailed understanding of clusterIP service and go through this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service#what-is-a-service) for how the service works.

Comment: I have the services using clusterIp's already. I think the problem is the ingress configuration. I got it working but I have 4 external load balancers and hard coded the appropriate IP's into the React App's .post/get requests. I know there is a better way than this though. The other services running on the clusterIp's are working as intended though.

Comment: @CurtisBotonis are you facing issue with ingress? can you brief your issue.